# JTextArea ran out of room? How much text can fit, can I fit more than that?

Tags: java, text, bigdata

I am working on a visualizer for a pattern I found in prime numbers. Here is a link to the maths about it from StackMath:[Patterns In Primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371434/has-anyone-found-a-pattern-in-prime-numbers/371537?noredirect=1#comment798164_371537) and the full code from StackCodeReview:[Optimization of the Code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25436/help-me-speed-up-this-java-code-deals-with-huge-list-of-ints)

My problem seems to be I am running out of room in my JTextArea.

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at javax.swing.text.GapContent.allocateArray(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.GapVector.resize(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.GapVector.shiftEnd(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.GapContent.shiftEnd(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.GapVector.open(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.GapVector.replace(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.GapContent.insertString(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JTextArea.append(Unknown Source)
 at PrimeSandbox.main(PrimeSandbox.java:67)
```

Line 67:

```
 screen.append(Arrays.toString(primesLL.toArray()) + "\n");
```

So the only thing I can figure is that I have to much text in the TextArea. Can I increase the size it can hold? Or must I create a method to save some of the not shown text to a string and rewrite it when I scroll? (I really don't want to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty answer is to give yourself more heap space:

`java -Xmx2g PrimeSandbox`  ← gives you 2GB, for example

Whether this is a good long term solution depends on whether you just need a "little bit more", or whether you have a rampant memory problem.

You won't achieve any memory savings by moving strings around within your application. A string displayed in a `JTextArea` is not going to be any more memory intensive than a string in  a field in a class. Writing out to disk would be your only other option.

Comment: Ohh so this has to do with the entire program itself, It took up all the space the OS gave to it?

Comment: @BumSkeeter Yes. It may just be chance that the exception occurred where it did. You either have a memory leak (e.g. holding onto objects when you shouldn't), or you just need more memory. In the latter case, increase the heap. In the former case, profiling might help you.

Comment: Can you look at the link to my code in the OP and let me know which case you think it is? I am pretty sure it is just that I ran out of memory. I am working with a list of 71K prime numbers. So it is a huge amount of data.